# JavaConfig No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, web.xml, spring-java-config

I followed tutorial on http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com.es/2014/07/spring-security-custom-filterchainproxy.html to create a **security filter using Java configuration** instead of XML.

The bean is not being created and the application fails to load:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:234)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3783)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4409)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:313)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
```

This is the `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>com.config.SecurityConfig</param-value>
      </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>test</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>COMUN</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

This is the `SecurityConfig` class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SecurityConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ResourceLoaderAware{

   private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;


   @Bean
   public FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain() throws Exception {

      AuthenticationManager am = authenticationManager();

      SecurityContextPersistenceFilter sif = getSecurityContextPersistenceFilter();
      J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter j2eePreAuthFilter = getJ2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter(am);
      LogoutFilter logoutFilter = getLogoutFilter(); 
      ExceptionTranslationFilter etf = getExceptionTranslationFilter();
      FilterSecurityInterceptor fsi = getFilterSecurityInterceptor(am);

      FilterChainProxy fcp = new FilterChainProxy(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(
         new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"),
         sif, j2eePreAuthFilter, logoutFilter, etf, fsi
      ));

      return fcp;
   }

    private FilterSecurityInterceptor getFilterSecurityInterceptor(AuthenticationManager am) {

        AccessDecisionVoter<Object> roleVoter = new RoleVoter();
        List<AccessDecisionVoter> decisionVoters = new LinkedList<AccessDecisionVoter>();
        decisionVoters.add(roleVoter);

        AffirmativeBased httpRequestAccessDecisionManager = new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
        httpRequestAccessDecisionManager.setAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions(false);

        FilterSecurityInterceptor filterSecurityInterceptor = new FilterSecurityInterceptor();
        filterSecurityInterceptor.setAuthenticationManager(am);
        filterSecurityInterceptor.setAccessDecisionManager(httpRequestAccessDecisionManager);

        LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>> requestMap = new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>>();
        List<ConfigAttribute> configs = new ArrayList<ConfigAttribute>();
        configs.add(new org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig("hasRole(ADMIN)"));
        requestMap.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"), configs);
        FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource filterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource = new ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource(
                requestMap, new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler());
        filterSecurityInterceptor
                .setSecurityMetadataSource(filterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource);

        return filterSecurityInterceptor;
    }

    private LogoutFilter getLogoutFilter() {
        org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter("/", new SecurityContextLogoutHandler());
        return logoutFilter;
    }

    private ExceptionTranslationFilter getExceptionTranslationFilter() {
        ExceptionTranslationFilter exceptionTranslationFilter = new ExceptionTranslationFilter(
                new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
        return exceptionTranslationFilter;
    }

    private SecurityContextPersistenceFilter getSecurityContextPersistenceFilter() {
        return new org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter();
    }

    private J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter getJ2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter(AuthenticationManager am) throws Exception {

        WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever mappableRolesRetriever = new WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever();
        mappableRolesRetriever.setResourceLoader(this.resourceLoader);
        mappableRolesRetriever.afterPropertiesSet();

        SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper = new SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper();
        userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper.setConvertAttributeToUpperCase(true);

        J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource 
            = new J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource();
        j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource.setMappableRolesRetriever(mappableRolesRetriever);
        j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource.setUserRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper(userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper);

        J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter = new J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter();     
        j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(am);
        j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationDetailsSource(j2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource);

        return j2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter;
    }

   @Bean
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {

      PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService preAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService = new PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService();;

      PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
      preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(preAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService);

      List<AuthenticationProvider> lProviders = new LinkedList<AuthenticationProvider>();

      lProviders.add(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider);

      AuthenticationManager am = new ProviderManager(lProviders);

      return am;
   }

    @Override
    public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader arg0) {
        this.resourceLoader = arg0;
    }       
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: That tutorial is quite bad imho. However the issue is that you hvae 2 `context-param`s with name `contextConfigLocation` last one wins.  However as mentioned the tutorial is pretty bad, you should use the proper java way for configuring (which means throw away  most of what you have and add `@EnableWebSecurity`) and use the proper ajva ways (I suggest a read of the spring security manual).

Comment: EnableWebSecurity is not available in the version of spring im using, that is why replaced by EnableWebMvc. Can I define the class and the xml as input to contextConfigLocation?

Comment: EnableWebSecurity has never been part of Spring it is part of Spring Security... And it should be `@EnableWebMvcSecurity`... If you aren't using a version that supports that annotation tha don't bother using java based configuration as that will only complicate things.

Comment: @Deinum replaced `@EnableWebMvc by EnableWebMvcSecurity, still the same, thought is enough with defining the bean in Configuration to be picked up on bootstrapping and created for the web.xml

Comment: Instead of replacing annotations, I suggest a read on what they do... `@EnableWebMvc` != `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` ... The first is for Spring MVC to be configured the other is for security you need both... Next to that without changing your configuration it doesn't really help. As stated please read the spring security reference guide on the configuration. I also don't get the fact that you use basic authentication and preauthentication together, which is more or less complicating things (which Spring Security can all do out-of-the-box).

Comment: at the end seemed removed both and worked ok just creates the bean using @Configuration and component-scan. you were quite right in comment one but don´t see why forcing to use annotations like EnableWebSecurity. most examples found using that annotation implement configure method and use HttpSecurity , which is what didn´t do here , may be better but wouldn´t know to translate all logic of creating filters to this different way.

Comment: tutorial was the closest example found for this, although didnt have to do the web.xml part

Comment: You don't need to create the filters as that is done by `@EnableWebMvcSecurity`... That is the whole point of using that annotation. Also they way of implementing basic authentication and passing it to spring security is too complex in the tutorial as you only need to configure `http.basic()` and have it running, without additional filters and web.xml configuratin. So instead of looking at an old tutorial (Spring security 3.1) take a look at the samples and guides instead.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum. just tried to translate to java one xml configuration given. wasnt sure if that annotation would create the same filters and if it was possible since most examples found were for Spring4. I use the filtering basically as another layer of security but the login happens in Jboss. Can it be setup to use the same filters in the same order with annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit different from the example and simplified for this case, the filter class is created if its package is set on component-scan

The following part of the web.xml is **not needed:**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.config.SecurityConfig</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

The web.xml defines the application context which will scan the class and create an instance of the filter. Later the instance is used in the web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/application-context-${environment}.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If the ${environment} variable is "DEV", it uses an application context that has the security defined in XML, if the ${environment} variable is "PRO", it uses the following application context which has the logic defined in Java:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.config" />
</beans>
```

The filter only needs created in PRO so it needs the component-scan only for its package from within the application-context used in PRO.